# como rolar um scroll de uma div fora dela

Tags: javascript, jquery

estou com a seguinte situação tenho uma tela onde tem um scroll infinity até ai tudo bem ele funciona normal pegando o próximo registro quando se usa o scroll, o problema ocorre quando tento usar o scroll do mouse fora da div. Gostaria que funcionasse também fora, parecido com o do facebook a mediada que uso o scroll fora da timeline ele abaixa mesmo tanto fora da timeline. alguém sabe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

coloca esse código na "raiz" (fora de outras funções) do código.

```
window.onscroll = function() {executaFuncaoAqui()};
```

Comment: Faz sentido vou tentar aqui

Comment: Valeu @Luiz Felipe Nalin Borges era isso mesmo coloquei meu código que chama os próximo registros dentro desse evento e funcionou.

Comment: maravilha! Feliz em ter ajudado